# sideways for equation (a big matrix)

Tags: rotating

I hope to use `sideways` for my big matrix, like [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1703) and [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=3536).
It looks straight forward. But it's not working for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} \\
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a2+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a3}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a3}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a4}} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a4}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a4+m)}} &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5+m}} \\
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a2+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a4+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5+m}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{sideways}

\end{document}
```

But it does not seem to be working.
[image]

I would expect that it takes maths environments?

Comment: Compared to Stefan's answer, you're missing a `minipage` environment. So it should go `\begin{sideways}\begin{minipage}{\textheight}\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}\end{equation}\end{minipage}\end{sideways}`

Comment: Yes, I just noticed! But I did not think it was necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I would much more prefer to fit the matrix in (with my Copy Editor hat on). A lot of data is repeated, which gives some space for manipulation:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \phi_1^{-1} &
        \phi_1^{-1} &
        \phi_1^{-1} &
        \phi_1^{-1} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        \phi_2^{-1} &
        \phi_2^{-1} &
        \phi_2^{-1} &
        \phi_2^{-1} &
        \phi_2^{-1} &
        \phi_2^{-1} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        \phi_3^{-1} &
        \phi_3^{-1} &
        0 &
        \phi_3^{-1} &
        \phi_3^{-1} &
        \phi_3^{-1} &
        \phi_3^{-1} &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        \phi_4^{-1} &
        0 &
        0 &
        \phi_4^{-1} &
        0 &
        \phi_4^{-1} &
        \phi_4^{-1} \\
        f(b_2) &
        g(b_2) &
        g(b_2) &
        g(b_2) &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        f(a_3) &
        g(a_3) &
        g(a_3) &
        f(b_3) &
        g(b_3) &
        g(b_3) &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        f(a_4) &
        g(a_4) &
        0 &
        f(a_4) &
        g(a_4) &
        f(b_4) &
        g(b_4) &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        f(a_5) &
        0 &
        0 &
        f(a_5) &
        0 &
        f(a_5) &
        f(b_5) \\
        f(b_2) &
        g(b_2) &
        g(b_2) &
        g(b_2) &
        f(b_3) &
        g(b_3) &
        g(b_2) &
        f(b_4) &
        g(b_4) &
        f(b_5)
    \end{bmatrix}
,\end{equation}
where
\[
    f(a) \coloneqq \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^a}
,\quad
    g(a) \coloneqq \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a}}
\quad\text{and}\quad
    b_i \coloneqq a_i+m
.\]

\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for making the document more readable rather than answering the question as asked:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Answering questions as they're asked is no fun :P

Comment: This was thought about. However, my purpose was to illustrate a specific task. So can't really use this "shorthand".

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Then I would really like to know what the task is that makes rotating a matrix (and confusing the reader) better than substituting parts like this. It would have been even better to simply transpose the matrix than to rotate it. Caring to come to the chat at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends please? :)

Answer (score 16):

`rotating` package's `sideways` environment is really just for compatibility with the LaTex2.09 version, it is just a thin wrapper around `\rotatebox` giving the old syntax.

But box commands take you out of math mode so you need `$` to get back in:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
    \rotatebox{90}{$\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} \\
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a2+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a3}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a3}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a4}} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a4}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a4+m)}} &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5+m}} \\
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a2+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a4+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5+m}}
    \end{bmatrix}$}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The contents of a `sideways` environment are stored in an `\hbox` for later processing. Inside an `\hbox`, display math is not recognized. (TeX calls this "inner horizontal mode"). One needs to switch to "vertical mode" by wrapping the contents in a `\parbox` or a `minipage` environment. Thus

```
\begin{sideways}
  \parbox{8in}{
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2
  \end{equation}
  }
\end{sideways}
```

Note that your matrix, when turned sideways, is too tall for a normal page size. It will still be placed, but somehow it ends up on the next page unless it fits on one page.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to `sideways` as David solves for you. You could consider `landscape` from the `lscape` package, which respects math mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_1} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_2} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_3} &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} &
        \frac{1}{\phi_4} \\
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a2+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a3}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a3}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a4}} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-a4}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a4+m)}} &
        0 \\
        0 &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        0 &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        0 &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5+m}} \\
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a2+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a3+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a3+m)}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a2+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a4+m}} &
        \frac{-1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{-(a4+m)}} &
        \frac{1}{1+\mathrm{e}^{a5+m}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```